# User Properties not effect

Tags: flurry

it was normal for my app to use User Properties retention before,
but it has been abnormal after September 20th, all of them are 0.
What is the reason for this, please help me. Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide further details about how you are viewing User Property Retention?

Comment: I just view Analytics Retention by adding User Property Filter, and than only one day data, others are 0, It works fine before September 22. I don't kown why. Can you help me? Thanks!

Comment: @FlurryAnalyticsSupport  I just view Analytics Retention by adding User Property Filter, and than only one day data, others are 0, It works fine before September 22. I don't kown why. Can you help me? Thanks!

Comment: Can you email support@flurry.com with the specific app details? We can investigate.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.